# Is there a way to make a VBA code run a Python code?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have read all online questions on this problem and none of them seem to be working for me. I want to write a code in VBA such that when a button is pressed, my code in Python automatically starts running.

I am getting a file not found error when I run the code but I have checked the path and I know it is correct.

The code I am trying is:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Shell("C:/Users/RGilsburg/New folder/pythonw.exe" & "F:/Asset/Global/Port/untitled1.py")
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me where the error is?

Comment: can you make it run a batch file that runs the python?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: i would think make a batch file that runs the python, and then point the `Shell` function at that instead of the python script

Comment: I created a batch file. When I run the VBA code, the command file flashes briefly and goes away but the python file does not run.

Comment: You can have a Python class callable from Excel VBA, https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/python-pandas-vba-return-pandas-pivot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell command should work, however, you have some issues with the command to be executed:

- You need to put a blank between the Python command and the python file.
- Use the backslash, not the slash if you are on windows
- If a file contains a blank, you have to put it in Double quotes `"`. When you want to have a quote character in a string in VBA, you have to double it.

Basically, the parameter to `Shell` should be the same as you would enter it on a command prompt. To check this, write the command into a string variable and write this to the immediate window (Ctrl+G). Copy it from there and paste it into a `CMD`-window.

Try

```
Dim python as string, script as string, cmd As String
python = """C:\Users\RGilsburg\New folder\pythonw.exe"""
script = "F:\Asset\Global\Port\untitled1.py"
cmd =  python & " " & script
Debug.print cmd

Shell cmd
```

Comment: I tried this and my file not found error is gone but the python file is still not running

Comment: Is it running when you call it from the Windows cmd-shell? Do you need `pythonw.exe` or `python.exe`? If the script runs without user intervention, the shell window will be closed after the script finishes.

Comment: How can you tell if the python script was executed or not? Does it have any output, does it write or move any files, does it show a window, does it write a logfile? Can you put something like `os.read` at the beginning or end so that the script stops before it terminates?

Comment: My python script is supposed to do solve an optimization problem and output it into an excel file. When I run the file independently, I get the desired output in the excel file.

Comment: But you don't try to write into the Excel file that is currently open? I have no experience with Python writing into Excel, but I doubt that this will work.

Comment: No I am writing into a new excel file since I was told modifying an existing file is not possible.

Comment: Remains the question if the script is not called at all or if it is called but fails to do its job. Impossible to tell. Maybe start with a `HelloWorld` script and check if this is called.

Comment: Could this have something to do with where my executable is stored? The default path of the executable is generally different so maybe that is interfering with the process?

Answer (score 0):

this may be a bit ignorant of me since i know nothing of python and little of vba but did you add python as a reference in the vba editor.

if not

go to the tools dropdown in the vba editor select references and see if you can find python.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of Python to reference to.

Comment: maybe look at this i cant really test the code they have i don't have python